# Como definir un archivo y la ruta donde los logs van a guardarse

Tags: java, logger

Quiero implementar el uso de logs en java, estaba mirando esta guía

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950557/good-examples-using-java-util-logging

y veo que hay que usar

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ClassName.class.getName() );
```

la verdad nose si esto tiene un método o funcionalidad que me guarde en un archivo, ahora mismo lo que se me ocurre es hacer un filewriter que guarde todo lo que el log vaya imprimiendo en consola, ¿o hay una forma mas sencilla que esa? si alguien sabe una buena guía completa o algo con gusto la leeré.

gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Daniel, yo batallé mucho leyendo diferentes artículos de logging. Al final me di cuenta que si hubiera leído la documentación que vienen en cada una de las clases de java.util.logging, hubiera batallado mucho menos y entendido mejor. Además la documentación es corta y son pocas clases.

Hay una clase en particular que guarda los logs en archivo: java.util.logging.FileHandler

Y es tan fácil de configurar uno sencillo así:

Logger.addHandler(new FileHandler(nombreDeArchivo));

Te paso la liga del paquete:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html

Comment: Te comento que la liga que te mando viene en inglés. De momento no tengo alguna liga para logging en español.

Comment: Muchas gracias Alberto, le echare un vistazo no te preocupes tambien entiendo ingles asi que sientete libre de dejar guias en ingles jaja gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Hola de dejo un ejemplo de como escribir java.util.logging.Logger en un archivo:

```
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class EscribirLog {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

                                            //Nombre del archivo
        FileHandler handler = new FileHandler("default.log");

        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(EscribirLog.class.getName());
        logger.addHandler(handler);

        logger.severe("severe message");

        logger.warning("warning message");

        logger.info("info message");

        logger.config("config message");

        logger.fine("fine message");

        logger.finer("finer message");

        logger.finest("finest message");

    }
}
```

yo personalmente te recomendaría que utilices una mejor opción como Log4j, slf4j o LogBack para tus proyecto porque el Log con java.util es muy simple y poco flexible, mientras que estas otras opciones te permiten configurar el Log desde un archivo de configuración en tu proyecto, agregar políticas en los tamaños del archivo, hacer log en diferentes archivos según la ruta de donde se generen y muchos otros casos. Te dejo un link en español para logback http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Primeros_pasos_con_logback